# Is there a Java library similar to Rust's tracing crate for dealing with Concurrent code?

Tags: library, java

I had been thinking a bit about how this could be done..
Some thoughts I had were AOP and JMX..
But are there any libraries that could do something similar to the Rust crate [tracing](https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.19/tracing/)

Particularly useful if you were say trying to make sense of the iterator logic say in Java's [ConcurrentHashMap - circa lines 3300](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java). (Traverser, & pushState/recoverState methods).

Are there any similar libraries that allow you to annotate constructors/method calls and fire off events, that a listener could collate and aggregate back for you in the Java sphere that anyone knows of?

Comment: What could be a cause for a downvote here?

Comment: So, basically, you want to trace the control flow, which functions are entered in what scope and order?

Comment: Yes exactly. Also dump out variables.. and hopefully group them by what thread they belong to. That way I can get my head around the behaviour of the multi-threaded code.